# repaint() method not getting called

Tags: java, swing, repaint

So I made a program where users can draw dots on the screen depending on where they click and then it draws lines from each dot to the next dot. Now I want to make it so another JFrame pops up where the user can choose to change the colour of the dots(vertex), the background or the lines(edges).  The code I  have thus far is:

```
// Fig. 14.34: Painter.java
// Testing PaintPanel.
public class Painter
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   { 
      // create JFrame
      JFrame application = new JFrame( "A simple paint program" );

      PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel(); // create paint panel
      ColorChanger myColorChanger = new ColorChanger();
      application.add( paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER ); // in center

      // create a label and place it in SOUTH of BorderLayout
      application.add( new JLabel( "Drag the mouse to draw" ), 
         BorderLayout.SOUTH );

      application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      application.setSize(600, 600 ); // set frame size
      application.setVisible( true ); // display frame
   } // end main
} // end class Painter
```

Class PaintPanel (Class that draws the lines and dots on the screen)

```
// Fig. 14.34: PaintPanel.java
// Using class MouseMotionAdapter.

public class PaintPanel extends JPanel
{
   private int pointCount = 0; // count number of points

   // array of 10000 java.awt.Point references
   private Point[] points = new Point[100];
   private String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   private Color backgroundColour = Color.GRAY;
   private Color edgeColour = Color.WHITE;
   private Color vertexColour = Color.WHITE;
   private Color textColour = Color.BLACK;

   // set up GUI and register mouse event handler
   public PaintPanel()
   {
       setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       setBackground(backgroundColour);
      // handle frame mouse motion event
       addMouseListener(
               new MouseAdapter() // anonymous inner class
               {
                   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                       points[pointCount] = e.getPoint();
                       //Subtract 15 from both x and y so the middle of the circle is drawn where we click
                       points[pointCount].x -= 15;
                       points[pointCount].y -= 15;
                       pointCount++;
                       repaint(); //THIS repaint() IS BEING CALLED
                   }
               } // end anonymous inner class
       ); // end call to addMouseMotionListener
   } // end PaintPanel constructor

   public void changeBackground(Color newColour) {
       System.out.println("Paint Panel change");
       backgroundColour = newColour;
       edgeColour = newColour;
       repaint(); //repaint() NOT BEING CALLED
   }

   public void changeEdge(Color newColour) {
       edgeColour = newColour;
       repaint(); //repaint() NOT BEING CALLED
   }

   // draw ovals in a 4-by-4 bounding box at specified locations on window
   public void paint( Graphics g )
   {
      System.out.println("PAINTCOMPONENT");
      super.paintComponent( g ); // clears drawing area
      System.out.println("paintComponent backgroundColour = " + backgroundColour);
      setBackground(backgroundColour);
      g.setColor(textColour);
      Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20);
      g.setFont(myFont);
      // draw all points in array
      for ( int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++ ) {
         g.setColor(vertexColour);
         g.fillOval( points[ i ].x, points[ i ].y, 30, 30 );
         g.setColor(textColour);
         g.drawString(Character.toString(alphabet.charAt(i % 26)), points[i].x + 10, points[i].y + 20);
         g.setColor(edgeColour);
         if(i > 0) {
             g.drawLine(points[i].x + 15, points[i].y + 15, points[i-1].x + 15, points[i-1].y + 15);
         }
      }
   } // end method paintComponent
} // end class PaintPanel
```

Class ColorChanger (Opens JFrame that shows three JButtons (to change colour of line, dots or background):

```
public class ColorChanger extends PaintPanel {
    JFrame myFrame;
    JButton background, edge, vertex;
    public ColorChanger() {
        myFrame = new JFrame("Color select tool");
        myFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        myFrame.setSize(500, 100);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        background = new JButton("Change background colour");
        edge = new JButton("Change edge colour");
        vertex = new JButton("Change vertex colour");
        background.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        edge.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        vertex.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        myFrame.add(background);
        myFrame.add(edge);
        myFrame.add(vertex);

    }
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() ==  background) {
                changeBackground();
            } else if (e.getSource() == edge) {
                changeEdge();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Vertex");
            }   
        }
    }
    private void changeBackground() {
        System.out.println("ColorChanger change Background");
        super.changeBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    private void changeEdge() {
        System.out.println("change  edge");
        super.changeEdge(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

So this program successfully draws the dots and connects the lines but my problem is that it will not change the colour of anything because the `repaint()` calls in class `PaintPanel` wont work except for the first one inside the anonymous inner class

Comment: Don't override `paint` and then proceed to break the paint chain. Override `paintComponent` instead and then call it's `super` method. Don't change the state of the component from within any paint method (for example, don't call `setBackground`), this will cause a never ending repaint cycle

Comment: Based on you example code, I don't see where `ColorChanger` is ever used or what effect it would have on the instance of `PaintPanel` which is displayed on the screen. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer In my Painter class I have the line `ColorChanger myColorChanger = new ColorChanger`

Comment: Yes, but that's all you have. What relationship does it have to the instance of `PaintPanel`?  How would calling it's `changeBackground` method change the instance of `PaintPanel`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer What im trying to do (and maybe im doing it incorrectly) but inside of the method `changeBackground()` inside of class ColorChanger I call the method `super.changeBackground()` so it calls the `changeBackground` method in class PaintPanel and then it changes paintpanel from that method

Comment: You have an instance of `ColorChanger` and and instance of `PaintPanel`, they are two separate entities, with their own state. You "seem" to be trying to change the state of one instance via the instance of another, but I could be mistaken, but that's how your question seems to read. Let me put it this way.  If I make a copy of you and pinch it, will you feel it?